# Scrapy crawl multiple pages error filtered duplicate

Tags: python, scrapy

Just started using scrapy, and I am trying to do a generic sort of search engine through the whole database page by page and grab certain links that has what I need, but I am getting this error when I try to go to the next page. Not exactly sure how to go to the next page either, would appreciate any help with the correct method!

This is my code:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "PLC"
    allowed_domains = ["exploit-db.com"]

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.exploit-db.com/local/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        links = response.xpath('//tr/td[5]/a/@href').extract()
        description = response.xpath('//tr/td[5]/a[@href]/text()').extract()    

        for data, link in zip(description, links):
            if "PLC" in data:
                with open(filename, "a") as f:
                    f.write(data+'\n')
                    f.write(link+'\n\n')
                    f.close()


            else:
                pass

        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"][1]//a/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0])
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

but I am getting this error(?) on the console

```
2016-06-08 16:05:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-06-08 16:05:21 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-08 16:05:21 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-08 16:05:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-06-08 16:05:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exploit-db.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-06-08 16:05:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exploit-db.com/local/> (referer: None)
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exploit-db.com/local/?order_by=date&order=desc&pg=2> (referer: https://www.exploit-db.com/local/)
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exploit-db.com/local/?order_by=date&order=desc&pg=1> (referer: https://www.exploit-db.com/local/?order_by=date&order=desc&pg=2)
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.exploit-db.com/local/?order_by=date&order=desc&pg=2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1162,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 40695,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 8, 5, 23, 514161),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 8, 5, 21, 561678)}
2016-06-08 16:05:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

it cannot crawl the next page and would love an explanation why T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parameter dont_filter = True in your request:

```
if next_page:
     url = response.urljoin(next_page[0])
     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

But you will run into an infinite loop, since it seems that **your xpath is retrieving the same link twice** (check the pager on each page, because the second element of .pagination may not always be the "next page".

```
next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"][1]//a/@href').extract()
```

Also, what if they start using bootstrap or similar, and they add the classes btn btn-default to the link?

I'd suggest to use

```
selector.css(".pagination").xpath('.//a/@href')
```

instead